# How to send text to GHCi process?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm working on [Haskell presentation engine Howerpoint](https://github.com/fokot/howerpoint). It is running in GHCi. I would like to create a function which would output a statement to current running GHCi session. It must work on Linux and Mac, Windows is not necessary. Function probably will have type

```
executeStatement :: String -> IO ()
```

What I tried already:

- `getProcessID` and `getParentProcessID` and then sending something like

  ```
  echo 'xxx' > /proc/92856/fd/1
  -bash: /proc/92856/fd/1: No such file or directory
  ```
- I also tried `runCommand` but it executes command in the Bash and not in GHCi so I got error that the command was not found
- `xdotool` does not run on mac

Comment: Unless "output" and "fd/1" are both typos, then how is this different than just `putStrLn`? In general your best bet will probably be to use `System.Process` to run your own GHCI process which will give you actual access to the standard input and output of the process in a (mostly) platform independent way. This will almost certainly be the easiest way to interact with any process.

Comment: It's not very clear what you mean by 'output a statement to current running GHCi session'. You don't normally output 'statements', whatever they are, you output strings. And you output strings to files, not to running programs. It may happen that a program reads a pipe, in which case you can output something to the other end of the pipe. But terminals are not pipes and have no 'other end'. (Well they actually do but you probably don't want to deal with this mess; your session may or not may read from a terminal anyway). What is your *real* goal? What should your users see/be able to do?

Comment: I'm taking inspiration form Scala program. I want to do this https://asciinema.org/a/16690 look at 1:25. You see a code in the slide (written to text output) and when he run r function the code is copied from the slide to the actual scala interpreter and evaluated as if he wrote it there. But scala has library to interact with interpreter, IMO ghci does not have it.

Comment: thanks for help @user2407038. where are the typos?

Comment: I see the problem - indeed they are typos. You want to send *input* to the GHCI session (i.e. to stdin which is fd0 as far as I remember). However the method of piping to `proc/.../fd/..` will probably not work. If you want to run the actual code represented by a string, you will need to use the GHC api or some wrapper like [hint](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint). Note that this doesn't allow you to interact with the *current* ghci process (in fact it rarely works when run from the interpreter at all) but you can simply start a GHCI process from your application.

Comment: thanks @user2407038 again. i tried ../fd0, ../fd/0, ../fd1, ../fd/1 with process id as well as parent process id and nothing works.

Will I achive the same if i run new ghci? will i be able to send keys to current session. i think only then it makes sense, because code on one slide can be dependent to the codes on the slides before. or maybe i will just print out the code to console and the presenter will need to copy paste it

Comment: As I said, there is guarantee that these file descriptors will *ever* be open - if you manage to find an edge case where any of them are, you can't rely on that behaviour whatsoever. When you start the GHCI process using the GHC api, you have complete control of its input and output through Haskell directly - not through `/proc/../fd`. You cannot send *keys* to the process, you may send *code* which it evaluates and executes, which should be fine for your purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [ghcid](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghcid) project from hackage to evaluate expressions. They would not be evaluated in the same session as your are currently running, but you can send expressions and read their output in *a* session nonetheless.
Here is an example:

```
import Language.Haskell.Ghcid

main :: IO ()
main = do 
    (g, _) <- startGhci "ghci" (Just ".") True 
    let executeStatement = exec g
    executeStatement "let x = 33"
    executeStatement "x + 8" >>= print . head
    executeStatement "print x" >>= print . head
    stopGhci g
```

The output is "41" "33" and g represents a ghci session.

If you really need to execute expressions in an already running ghci instance you can have a look at this function - [startGhci](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghcid-0.5.1/docs/src/Language-Haskell-Ghcid.html#startGhci) and instead of creating a new process you would have to tap into the existing process and then set std_in, std_out and std_err.

Comment: Thank you this looks really good. I need the current session, because I want the user to be able to change the things 0 do the live coding. I will give it a try

Answer (score 2):

You could use a terminal multiplexer like [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/) to execute **ghci** in one pane, and from another pane invoke **tmux** commands that send keystrokes to **ghci**.

[`tmux load-buffer`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1) lets you load text into a tmux clipboard (using `-` as the path reads from stdin).

```
# from within tmux
$ echo foo | tmux load-buffer -
$ tmux show-buffer
foo
```

`tmux paste-buffer` lets you paste the contents of a tmux clipboard into a pane:

```
$ tmux list-panes
0: [127x24] [history 1850/2000, 1343570 bytes] %0
1: [127x24] [history 0/2000, 0 bytes] %2 (active)
$ tmux paste-buffer -t %0
```

Another option, already mentioned in the comments, is to use the [**process**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process) library to launch a ghci process, and send the commands through piped stardard input.

Here's a small program that uses my [**process-streaming**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-streaming) helper package for **process** (not really required, you could do the same using **process** alone). *stdin* is piped, *stdout* and *stderr* inherited:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import System.Process.Streaming -- from process-streaming
import Pipes (lift,yield) -- from pipes
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)

main :: IO ()
main = executeInteractive program (feedProducer (do
    let delay = lift (threadDelay (1000000*6))
    delay
    yield "4 + 3\n"
    delay
    yield "5 + 3\n"))
  where
    program = (shell "ghci"){ std_in = CreatePipe }
```

The output is:

```
$ ./Main
GHCi, version 7.10.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> 7
Prelude> 8
Prelude> Leaving GHCi.
```