# How to use GHCi inside another application

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

Is it possible to use GHCi inside another application?

In particular I want to pass strings to ghci and receive answer as strings for processing.

I know there is way with interactive mode (ghc --interactive ) but this variant does not save context of computation.

So I would like to redirect communications with GHCi through my application. Is it possible to realize?

Comment: See this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35331801/how-can-i-send-programmatically-haskell-expression-to-current-running-ghci-sessi

Comment: I suggest you use the Jupyter API and [IHaskell](https://github.com/gibiansky/IHaskell) instead. I'm pretty sure that there are already some guides on how to embed jupyter consoles into other applications, since there's plenty of tools already doing this.